# Can a user delete data stored in shared preferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Suppose i made an app which uses shared preferences,
will the data stored with shared preferences be deleted when user clears app storage?

if yes then what is alternative to store/retrieve important data faster which will not get erased by user?

i tried firebase-database, but it is lagging the speed/performance i require.

Comment: Try using sql lite database. Shared preference get removed when user clear storage and so do sql lite dabs if you create it via using code snipped so instead of this use sql file put it in your app then insert in that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will the data stored with shared preferences be deleted when user clears app storage?

Yes.

> what is alternative to store/retrieve important data faster which will not get erased by user?

Store it on a server.

> i tried firebase-database, but it is lagging the speed/performance i require.

Then store it on a faster server, I guess. Or, use a local file as a cache, with the server acting as a backup location, should you need to restore the data at a later point.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare for your answer. Could you be more specific about "faster server" because firebase is only familier system for me.